# Exporting a tab delimited file from an access database

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

This code:

```
db = "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\hom\Anwendungsdaten\BayWotch4\Neuer Ordner\baywotch.db5"
TextExportFile = "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\hom\Anwendungsdaten\BayWotch4\Neuer Ordner\Exp.txt"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open _
   "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
   "Data Source =" & db

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAuction1"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fs.CreateTextFile(TextExportFile, True, True)

a = rs.GetString

f.WriteLine a

f.Close
```

generates a tab delimited file, however it is not suitable for importing into mysql. I would like it to generate a file similar to a file produced by an access macro, which can be seen here:

http://www.yousendit.com/download/TTZtWmdsT01kMnVGa1E9PQ

The file produced by the vbscript is here:

http://www.yousendit.com/download/TTZtWmdsT00wVWtLSkE9PQ

I would also like to know why the file sizes differ by 50k or so.

**Edit:** The result from the vbscript file uses newline characters that are not recognized by notepad, so the above looks substantially messier when viewed. The macro does not seem to be exporting the html code, which explains why it is a smaller file, however the vbscript does not appear to be tab delimited, as it will not import into mysql.

**Edit:** the files look ok under a linux system, so it could be something to do with windows handling. However it is still not correct.

Comment: Are you using Access as a programming environment or just as a data store? If the former, why use ADO for coding against Jet data, when DAO is Jet's native data interface? And if it's not Access you're programming in, then you're not using Access but only Jet. Distinctions matter for usable answers.

Comment: I am using Access just as a datastore. I am using ADO because that is the advice I was given to use, in a previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Both files contain what looks like tab-delimited data as well as HTML code (generated by some MS Office app, by the looks of it). Does tblAuction1 store any OLE Objects? Perhaps when you're exporting those objects it's exporting the file contents?

Comment: the html code is retrieved from ebay auction websites by another program. there are no ole obnjects as far as i know. at least on my windows xp system, and according to vbscript, the vbscript generated file is not tab delimited in the same way the access one is.

Comment: Do you know anything else it could be?

Comment: You could run into issues of the HTML text has tabs embedded in it; the import program will interpret this as the start of a new field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoding issue to me. I see that you are passing the Unicode parameter when you create the text file, but there is clearly an encoding difference between the two files.

Comment: Is that definitely the problem? The access macro exports as unicode as well..so it should not be a problem..

Comment: Well I can't say that it is definitely *the* problem, but when I look at the files they are definitely *not* encoded the same.

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal of this project?  What is the purpose of creating the file?  If you are just looking to move data from Access to MySQL, why not do it directly with something like this

```
Const Access = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\hom\Anwendungsdaten\BayWotch4\Neuer Ordner\baywotch.db5"
Const SQLServer = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"
Dim arrFields

Set SQLConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
WITH SQLConn
    .ConnectionString = SQLServer
    .Open
End WITH
Set AccessConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
WITH AccessConn
    .ConnectionString = Access
    .Open
End WITH
Set SQLRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
WITH SQLRS
    .CursorType = 3
    .LockType = 3
End WITH
Set AccessRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
WITH AccessRS
    .ActiveConnection = AccessConn
    .CursorType = 3
    .LockType = 3   
End WITH

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblAuction1" 
AccessRS.Open strSQL

If AccessRS.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    AccessRS.MoveFirst
    ReDim arrFields(AccessRS.Fields.Count)
    Do Until AccessRS.BOF OR AccessRS.EOF
        For i = 0 To AccessRS.Fields.Count - 1
            If AccessRS.Fields(i).Type = 202 Then 
                arrFields(i) = Chr(39) & AccessRS.Fields(i).Value & Chr(39)
            Else
                arrFields(i) = AccessRS.Fields(i).Value
            End If
        Next
        strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO {Table in mySQL} VALUES("
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrFields) - 2 
            strSQL1 = strSQL1 & arrFields(j) & ","
        Next
        strSQL1 = strSQL1 & arrFields(UBound(arrFields) - 1) & ")"
        SQLRS = SQLConn.Execute(strSQL1)
        AccessRS.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "No records found"
End If
```

This will add all of the records returned by the recordset to a table in an SQLExpress database,it should not be difficult to tweak to your needs (if your needs are transferring data from one database to another).

Comment: Is this a better approach then importing after exporting to a text file?

Comment: If it works why not?  Why move the data twice when you can move it once, middlemen always increase cost and delay delivery.

Comment: I second tester101.myopenid.com. Fewer moving parts is (mostly) always good.